# Javascript choose biggest more often than smaller

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm busy with nodejs a bit for modding a game, but I'd like to know how to do something like this:

```
var zombieDirector = 
{
zombieBison = 1
zombieChicken = 2
zombie = 3
skeleton = 3
}
```

and those names have another var like

```
var zombieBison = 'Entities/Zombies/zombieBison.cfg'
```

and now make the Bison spawned rare and skeleton and zombie more often.
you get this, where randomZombie equals to 'Entities/Zombies/aZombie.cfg'
`ks.map.spawnEntity('zombie', randomZombie, 0, 0, 3);`
I can't get any further than

```
    var randomZombie = zombieDirector[Math.floor(Math.random() * zombieDirector.length)];
```

On another note: No JQuery please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, you're talking about weighted random number generation. A little tricky, if you want to use math, but you can do it with an array, like this:

```
var choices = [];
for(prop in zombieDirector) {
    for(var i = 0; i<zombieDirector[prop]; i++) {
        choices.push(prop);
    }
}

var choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length + .5)];
```

The variable `choice` will now have a random monster name, weighted based on the number you provide in `zombieDirector`.

Comment: If not using math is easier, give me another example if you want to :) thanks already for this!

Comment: This was actually the math-less example. :) If it helped, please consider accepting and upvoting my answer.

Comment: I'm having problems with 'prop in zombieDirector', what it exactly has to be? I tried something like this but it gave 'undefined'